# C# Cascading forms without mdi parent?

Tags: c#, cascade

I have been working on a project in C#, a portion of it requires multiple instances of a window to open. Is there any easy way to cascade the instances of the form? I'm assuming I'd have to deal with the math required manually. I just cannot wrap my head around it, any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Painful, you have to know the Z-order.  That requires pinvoking GetWindow().  Rethink your windowing model, you've got too many.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want the forms to appear on screen in a cascade effect:

[image: Cascade]

If so, when using WinForms you can do this by ensuring that the [`StartPosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.startposition.aspx) property of each form is set to `FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation` (which it is by default).

If you are using WPF, you need to set the [`WindowStartupLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.windowstartuplocation.aspx) property to `WindowStartupLocation.Manual` in a similar manner and not set a specific location for the window.

This leaves Windows to position the form when it displays, which it does by using the cascading effect shown in the picture.

Comment: I set WindowStartupLocation to Manual, with undefined Top and Left... Windows XP doesn't cascade.  Sometimes the new window overlaps. sometimes it "cascades" 200 pixels away. Not nice at all.