# Cascade windows in a non MDI C++/CLI application

Tags: c#, c++, modal-dialog

I would like to implement a cascade layout in my application.
I cannot use FormStartPosition.WindowsDefaultLocation as per the below answer

[C# Cascading forms without mdi parent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560081/c-sharp-cascading-forms-without-mdi-parent)

Even though cascading is achieved using this approach, each time windows are coming at different different locations.

I want to display windows at fixed positions preferably starting from CentreScreen and going towards the bottomroght direction

Extra Info: This is a tray icon application and each form is displayed Modally by calling ShowDialog().

please help!!

Thanks & Regards,

Rohini

Comment: If you are going to show the windows modally (`Form.ShowDialog()`) why are you so worried about a cascade layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to show the windows modally `Form.ShowDialog()` I'm not really sure a cascade layout is really necessary. Just set `StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent` and you should be good to go.

If you really insist on doing a manual cascade then set `Form.StartPosition` to `FormStartPosition.Manual`. This enables you to define the starting point of the `Form` through the `Form.Location` property.

Typically, you should do this overriding `Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)` and working your starting position based on the position of `Form.Owner`

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
     base.OnLoad(e);

     if (this.Owner != null)
     {
         this.Location = .... // offset this.Owner.Location
     }
}
```

Note that `Form.Location` is in global screen coordinates though it doesn't make a difference as you are working with offsets.

Comment: Thank you..As per your reply I understand that we need to set the offset of each form on Load with respect to the owner. But in my case, the forms are really independent and the order of the forms   may not be same always...so in that case, setting a fixed offset from owner may not be sufficient. ShowDialog() is not really relevant in my case, as each form is independently displayed using each of the context menu on the tray.

Comment: @RohiniSreekanth In your question you state that you are showing the forms modally through `ShowDialog()`. If that is the case, a user will only be able to open a new form from the currently active modal window in your application. `ShowDialog()` automatically sets the owner of the new `Form` to the currently active `Form` in your app so I don't understand your question. Order is irrelevant, you only need to offset the position relative to the current active (AKA Owner) `Form`

Comment: @RohiniSreekanth Ok, even though [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx) states that `ShowDialog()` will set the `Form.Owner` property to the currently active `Form` I just tried it out and it doesn't seem to do that. Don't have time to look into it. When you open the new form, explicitly set the owner: `Form.ShowDialog(Form owner)`

Comment: @RohiniSreekanth I missed the part of the tray icon application. Do not know how that works or even if windows will be modal even if you call `ShowDialog()`. The solution is still the same, like I said, explicitly set the owner when calling `ShowDialog(Form owner)`. You can either decide to cascade from the currently active Form (static property `Form.ActiveForm`) or you can rig some sort of logic that keeps track of opened and closed forms and gives you the correct owner form from which to offset the position (seems overcomplicating things for no real gain)

Comment: Thanks @InBetween...I used Application::OpenForms to find the open windows before showing my form, and from that count, I would find the offset needed. It does the job.